# Prompt Windows AD user to reset password upon login to Linux

Tags: rhel, samba, active-directory, winbind

I have a Red Hat Enterprise Linux VM which has been integrated with Windows AD using Kerberos and Winbind. It all works, bar one feature. In AD, I can reset the users password and select the option 'User must change password on next logon'. When I use this account to logon to Windows, I am obviously prompted to change the password. When I login via Linux (SSH) I am not prompted to change it. How can set this up so Linux prompts the user based on this option from AD:

[image: Force Password Reset]

Answer (score 1):

You haven't made it clear what version of RHEL you're using. I will assume you are using a supported version (6.8 or 7.3).

First thing's first, **winbind does not support password changes**, at least not natively. You can *maybe* make a pam configuration change to assist in this, but you may run into the dreaded `The change of the authentication token failed` error.

To make your life simpler, I highly suggest using `sssd` and `adcli/realm` to work with Active Directory. If using 7.3, you will have the `realm` command, which will automatically setup `sssd.conf`, `krb5.conf`, and your `pam.d` configurations in a sane manner. On 6.8, you will only have `adcli`, which will require some manual configuration changes on your part or using the `authconfig` command to setup sane defaults. Users that need their passwords changed will be prompted and it will work when using this method. It is supported and is recommended by Red Hat to use `sssd` and the `realm` or `adcli` commands.